# Select Max following effect of Where clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, max, row-number

Per code below, for each Contract (where ContractTypeID in [1, 2, etc] ) I want to return the MaxPrice for only contracts where ContractCurrency = 'USD' -- however there are 652 contracts (aka rows returned) with the WHERE Currency='USD' but 729 contracts/rows without a Currency clause.

I've failed using MAX() and ROW_NUMBER=1 (as well as previously trying Cursors and Cross Apply which both ran 90-120 seconds for the whole Stored Procedure) AND I comprehend that the issue for the ROW_NUMBER=1 strategy is that when the Max Price is not in USD the row that I want (i.e. the highest Price that is in USD) will be numbered 2+.

How can I return all 729 results (but with highest Price = the max in USD)?  TIA

```
    SELECT  MeasurableID,
            EntityID,
            MAX (ContractPrice) AS HighPrice

  FROM dbo.Contracts

  WHERE Contracts.CurrencyCode IN (
       ('USD'),
       ('BTC'),
       ('INR')                    )


    AND dbo.Contracts.MeasurableID IN (
            2030,
            2017
                                    )

    GROUP BY
           dbo.Contracts.MeasurableID,
           dbo.Contracts.EntityID       
    ORDER BY
           MeasurableID,
           EntityId
```

Comment: So, I didn't understand. Do you want select all rows but just with the max of USD?

Comment: Please provide a sample data set with a sample output.

Comment: As Andrew mentioned, provide input sample data and your desired output. Also, use sql fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) to build your schema and data. So, we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for conditional aggregation. This returns all 729 records, each with its maximum USD price, if any.

```
SELECT
  MeasurableID,
  EntityID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN CurrencyCode = 'USD' THEN ContractPrice END) AS HighPrice
FROM dbo.Contracts
WHERE CurrencyCode IN ('USD', 'BTC', 'INR')
  AND MeasurableID IN (2030, 2017)
GROUP BY MeasurableID, EntityID
ORDER BY MeasurableID, EntityID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replies but in creating a SQL Fiddle example I came to realize that if there are no contracts in the currencies specified then there will of course NOT be any row returned at all (I made an error in seeding my test db and had thought there was always a USD).

The conditional aggregation is useful, though for a different requirement/issue than I was struggling with.